# How to do a route alias within a Backbone Router?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

Having a route like `'dogs': 'process'`, I need to rewrite it to `'animals': 'process'`.

Now, I need the router to recognize both routes, but always display the url like `/animals`, it is sort of aliasing, but could not find any info on how to solve this without placing an url redirect in `'process'` handler.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to setup the names of all the animals in the world as alias to "animal". This is usually handled with a route having param like `'animal/:name':'process'` What benefit do you get from actually defining a route for "dog" or "cat" only to redirect it to "animals" and treated similarly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm assuming that the real need for aliases is different than `dogs` to `animals`, so I'll answer regardless of if the use-case here is good or not. But if you don't want to change the hash but want to trigger different behaviors in the app, using the router is probably not the route to go.*

**Route aliases don't really exist in Backbone**, other than defining different routes using the same callback. Depending on your exact use-case, there are multiple ways to handle similar routes.

## Replace the hash

To display the same hash for a generic route coming from different routes, use the `replace` option of the [`navigate` function](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate).

```
routes: {
    'lions': 'animalsRoute',
    'animals': 'animalsRoute'
},
animalsRoute: function() {
    this.navigate("#/animals", { replace: true });
    // or using the global history object:
    // Backbone.history.navigate("#/animals", { replace: true });
}
```

then handle the animals route, regardless of which route was initially used to get in this callback.

Some other answers or tutorials will say to use `window.location.hash` but don't. Manually resetting the hash will trigger the route regardless and may cause more trouble than it'll help.

### Different behaviors but showing the same route

Just use different callbacks, both using the replace trick above.

```
routes: {
    'lions': 'lionsRoute',
    'tigers': 'tigersRoute'
},
showGenericRoute: function() {
    this.navigate("#/animals", { replace: true });
},
tigersRoute: function() {
    this.showGenericRoute();
    // handle the tigers route
},
lionsRoute: function() {
    this.showGenericRoute();
    // handle the lions route
}
```

Notice the inexistent `animalsRoute`. You could add the route if there's a generic behavior if no specific animal is chosen.

## Use the route params

If you want to know which animal was chosen but still use the same callback and remove the chosen animal from the hash, use the [route params](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-routes).

```
routes: {
    'animals/:animal': 'animalsRoute',
},
animalsRoute: function(animal) {
    // removes the animal from the url.
    this.navigate("#/animals", { replace: true });

    // use the chosen animal
    var view = new AnimalView({ type: animal });
}
```

## Redirect to the generic route

If you want a different behavior but always show the same route, use different callbacks, then redirect. This is useful if the generic route is in another router instance.

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'animals': 'animalsRoute'
    },
    animalsRoute: function() {
        // handle the generic behavior.
    }
});

var PussyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'lions': 'lionsRoute'
        // ...
    },
    lionsRoute: function() {
        // handle lions, then redirect
        this.navigate("#/animals", { trigger: true, replace: true });
    }
});
```

Using the `trigger` options will call the `animalsRoute` in the other router and the `replace` option will avoid making an entry in the history, so pushing the back button won't go to `lions` to get back to `animals` and being caught in the animals route.

Comment: Thanks for help, so as expected, this needs js to be employed ;)